# How to use function keys on bluetooth keyboards in Android without pressing Fn?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, android, bluetooth, keyboard-layout, wireless-keyboard

I use an external Bluetooth keyboard Samsung EJ-BT230 with an Android device. I need <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys to use SSH terminal remotely (eg. for mc). Now, I'm able to use function keys when holding <kbd>Fn</kbd> button on the keyboard.

Is it possible to switch the operation of <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> to make them possible to be used without <kbd>Fn</kbd> button? Is there any solution like Fn-Lock which is present on laptops' keyboards or on laptops' BIOS? Or is there any way to remap the keys so I can swap the function key features?

Comment: most laptops have an option to revert the function keys to their original behavior but that's not Fn-lock. I'm not sure if the Fn-lock key exists on physical keyboards or not but it's not a common feature. Anyway this is off-topic so I've edited your question to make it on-topic. If you don't like it just revert the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> is not a real key that OSes recognize, since it doesn't produce a scan code (except on Mac keyboards). The keyboard controller sends the real scan code if you press <kbd>Fn</kbd> along with some other keys. Therefore if there's no physical <kbd>Fn-lock</kbd> key on your keyboard (which probably doesn't, as [some one commented](https://www.samsung.com/uk/mobile-accessories/universal-bluetooth-keyboard-bt230/)) you'll need to remap those keys on software

If you have **root permissions** there are various solutions to remap

- Map the keys manually by modifying the `/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl` layout file and copy it to `/system/usr/keylayout`

  - [A custom android layout for logitech tablet keyboard](http://gustavepate.github.io/blog/20130714/android-keyboard-layout-logitech-tablet-keyboard/)
  - [Remapping a Bluetooth keyboard on Android](http://rjw57.github.io/notes/technical/android-keyboard/)
- Use a software to do that heavy lifting

  - [Button Mapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.homebutton&hl=en)

If you have a **non-rooted** device then you can use [External Keyboard Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo). Just remap the scancode for <kbd>Home</kbd> to <kbd>F1</kbd> and vice versa. Similarly for other keys. You can see the [remap tutorial](http://blog.apedroid.com/2012/10/ekh-tutorial-2-remapping-some-keys.html) that shows you how to get <kbd>Esc</kbd> without <kbd>Fn</kbd> like in your keyboard

For more information you can read

- [Is there a keyboard application for setting an external keyboard to the Colemak layout](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/10535/42635)
- [Is there an app to change bt keyboard map?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1355620)
- [How to Use a Bluetooth Keyboard with Your Android Device](https://www.howtogeek.com/175267/the-htg-guide-to-using-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-your-android-device/)
- [How to Create Custom Shortcuts with Bluetooth Keyboard on Android](https://medium.com/@oyetoketoby80/how-to-create-custom-shortcuts-with-bluetooth-keyboard-on-android-149cd04c8453)
- [how to remap the keys on a bluetooth gamepad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30222236/995714)